# my usb is not accessible "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error"

Tags: usb-drive

i`m trying to open my USB and i have the message **drive is not accessible. The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error** 
[image]

Comment: The request should be addressed to http://superuser.com. Also does the USB port work with other devices? Does the USB drive in question work on another computers?

Comment: This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Easy step. It will be work for you.

1. Type CMD on your system search bar.
2. Right click and choose "Run as administrator".
3. Type **chkdsk /f [Drive:]**. Replace the [Drive:] to your removable drive letter. For e.g: If your USB drive letter is G:, then type **chkdsk /f G:**
4. Press "**Enter**" button to execute that command.

Now your USB can works fine and you can able to copy & paste your data.

Comment: Which of course will never work if the drive can't be mounted in the first place